# How to return cell address as string inside the cell ?

Tags: excel

I would like the cell A1 to return "A1" as a string and A2 to return "A2" and so forth dynamically.

I need a function call because I need these address values for another function call in those cells.

How can this be achieved ?

something like,

```
=THISCELL.ADDRESS()
```

and the Cell will hold it's address as a string.

Comment: enter formula `=CELL("address",A1)` in cell A1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in @simoco 's comment, use the [`CELL` function.](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/CELL-function-b98b713d-d3de-4148-829f-80c886af6410)

`=CELL("address", A1)` returns the string `$A$1`.